# How to select a row(s) from mysql table using checkbox (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, select, checkbox

Hi I have a page that displays all of the contents of my table. Alongisde each row of the table I also have a column containing a checkbox. When the user selects one or more rows by ticking the checkbox and pressing the submit button, I want just those rows to appear in a table on the next page (buy.php). I know it is basically a select statement per row that is selected. But I dont know how to approach this. Can anybody help? Thanks

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Shopping</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='buy.php' method='post'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form> 
<h1>Buy</h1>
<?php // Script 12.7 - sopping.php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', '#####', '#####');
mysql_select_db('shopping', $db);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM Items';

if ($r = mysql_query($query, $db)) { 
    print "<form>
    <table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        print 
        "<tr>
        <td>{$row['ID']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Cost']}</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='buy[{$row['ID']}] value='buy' /></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    print "</table>
    </form>";

} else { 
    print '<p style="color: blue">Error!</p>';
} 

mysql_close($db); // Close the connection.

?>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I tried the suggestion below and I did not get a table. Just the title of the page appeard:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Order Details</h1>
<?php // Script 12.7 - buy.php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', '#####', '#####');
mysql_select_db('shopping', $db);

foreach($_POST['buy'] as $item) {

$query = 'SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID = $item';

if ($r = mysql_query($query, $db)) { 
    print "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        print 
        "<tr>
        <td>{$row['ID']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Cost']}</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";

} else { 
    print '<p style="color: blue">Error!</p>';
} 
}

mysql_close($db);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a dynamic SQL query.

1) I suggest you change your checkbox to the following

```
<input type='checkbox' name='buy[]' value='{$row['ID']}' />
```

2) Loop through all of the buy options

```
<?php
  foreach($_POST['buy'] as $item) {
    // Append the ID (in the $item variable) to the SQL query, using WHERE `ID` = $item OR `ID` = $item and so on
  }
?>
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php // Script 12.7 - buy.php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', '#####', '#####');
mysql_select_db('shopping', $db);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ';

$item_count = count($_POST['buy']);

for($i = 0; $i < $item_count; $i++) {
  $itemid = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['buy'][i]); // Secures It
  $query .= '`ID` = '.$itemid;
  if($i +1 < $item_count) {
    $query .= ' OR ';
  }
}

if ($r = mysql_query($query, $db)) { 
    print "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        print 
        "<tr>
        <td>{$row['ID']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Cost']}</td>
        </tr>";
    }
print "</table>";
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: You should also note that some checks should be made on the value from the post and protect from sql injections :)

Comment: do i add the step 2 part in the coding for the new page? Also is this statement correct: SELECT * FROM Items WHERE 'ID' = $item

Comment: Step 2 is on the new page / process order page.  That sql statement is incorrect. 'ID' should be `\`ID\`` , use the key with ~. Column names use \` values use ' (single quote)

Comment: can i copy the table code from above into the loop so they display in a table

Comment: If you change the SQL query, yes.

Comment: I get a blank page (no table). I have show the code I used in the main question

Comment: I modified your script (not all of it) and this should work. Untested and coded really quickly.

Comment: I dont know what else I can do

Answer (score 0):

```
// this checkbox use 
<input type='checkbox' name='buy[]' value='{$row['ID']}' />


//buy.php
foreach($_POST['buy'] as $item) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID = $item";
//use " "

//   try it if any problem please carefully look you database table
// download file and try it 2file with table sql data

// https://copy.com/8ZsBAFj7LvypLJkK
```

Comment: // this checkbox use
<input type='checkbox' name='buy[]' value='{$row['ID']}' />

Answer (score 0):

// this checkbox use

//buy.php foreach($_POST['buy'] as $item) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID = $item"; //use " "

// try it if any problem please carefully look you database table // download file and try it 2file with table sql data

// https://copy.com/8ZsBAFj7LvypLJkK